# Virtual PDF printer to print from Firefox

Tags: windows, pdf, firefox, printing

There are some documents I need in PDF format. On a website it has the "print" button and it opens the standard options. I would like a simple, free "virtual PDF printer" that will save the document in PDF format.

[image: Printing options]

I use Firefox on Windows 10.

Comment: http://www.cutepdf.com/

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/printpdf/

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/print-edit/

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1109428

Comment: Print to file should have this ability also I believe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lightweight Windows Software for Printing to PDF](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/21429/lightweight-windows-software-for-printing-to-pdf)

Answer (score 3):

This one has always worked good for me
http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator

Comment: So this converts files to PDF, I was hoping for something that prints straight to PDF.

Comment: @Celeritas  When you goto print, "PDFCreator" is the name of the virtual printer it creates.

Answer (score 0):

The PDF24 Creator is a free desktop PC tool to convert every printable file to a PDF. https://en.pdf24.org/convert-to-pdf.jsp

There is also PDF-XChange Lite. A simplified version of PDF-XChange Standard virtual PDF printer. PDF-XChange 'Lite' is FREE for non commercial use. https://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-lite

Setting one of them as the default printer will let you print straight to PDF without need to select from the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

We use CutePDF at work (.edu) - http://www.cutepdf.com/Products/CutePDF/writer.asp

Answer (score 0):

Not free, but with a lot of features: Print&Share ( [www.printandshare.info](http://www.printandshare.info) ). We use it at work here.